# Weak $L_1$ convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, weak-convergence

Given a sequence $Y_{un}$, where $Y_{1n},Y_{2n},\ldots$ have the same domain. Assume for every $u\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $e^{itY_{un}}\rightarrow \mathbb{E}[e^{it M}]$ weakly in $L_1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. For the defintion see below.

Zhoraster gave an useful example under which i was needed to update the requirements.

Assume for the sequence of random variables $X_n$ it holds
$$
\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty} \limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{P}\left(d\left(X_n,Y_{un}\right)\geq \epsilon\right)=0 \tag1
$$

Can we conclude that $e^{itX_n}\rightarrow \mathbb{E}\left[e^{itM}\right]$ weakly in $L_1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

I think this should be possible:
Due to (1)  we have for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$ that $\mathbb{E}\left|e^{itX_{n}}-e^{itY_{un}}\right|\rightarrow 0$ as $u\rightarrow \infty$.

And one could formally use $Y_{un}\xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty }M_{u}:=M\xrightarrow{u\rightarrow \infty} M$.

We could then see this result as an improved version of Billingsley 1968 Theorem 4.2

If this is not the case: what about the condition (1) replaced by

$$
\lim_{u\rightarrow \infty} P\left(\sup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} d\left(X_n,Y_{un}\right)\geq \epsilon\right)=0 \tag{2}
$$

> Definition: Given a sequence of rv $Z_n$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ such that for all bounded $\mathcal{F}$-mb random variables $K$ it holds
>   $$
> \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[Z_nK\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[ZK\right],
> $$
>   we say $Z_n\rightarrow Z$ weakly in $L_1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was hinted in the comments, the result is not true unless you assume uniform convergence somewhere.

Here is a simple example. Let $X_n = X$ have non-degenerate Bernoulli distribution and $Y_{un} = X \mathbf{1}_{u\ge n}$. Then $P(Y_{un}\neq X_n)\to 0$, $u\to\infty$, and $e^{itY_{un}} \to 1$, $n\to\infty$, in all senses. However, $e^{itX_n} = e^{itX}\not\to 1$, $n\to\infty$, in any sense.

---

With the extra assumption (1), this is simple.

Write for any bounded $K$ and for arbitrary $u\ge 1$, $\varepsilon>0$ by the triangle inequality
$$
\left|\mathbb{E}[e^{itX_n}K] - \mathbb{E}[e^{itM}K]\right|\le \left|\mathbb{E}[e^{itX_n}K] - \mathbb{E}[e^{itY_{un}}K]\right| + \left|\mathbb{E}[e^{itY_{un}}K] - \mathbb{E}[e^{itM}K]\right|\\
\le \sup|K|\cdot\Big(\mathbb{E}\left[\left|e^{itX_n}-e^{itY_{un}}\right|\mathbf{1}_{|X_n-Y_{un}|>\varepsilon}\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[\left|e^{itX_n}-e^{itY_{un}}\right|\mathbf{1}_{|X_n-Y_{un}|\le\varepsilon}\right]\Big) \\
+ \left|\mathbb{E}[e^{itY_{un}}K] - \mathbb{E}[e^{itM}K]\right| \le \Big\{ |e^{ix}-e^{iy}|\le |x-y|\Big\}\\
\le \sup|K|\cdot \Big(2\mathbb{P}\left(|X_n-Y_{un}|>\varepsilon\right) + \varepsilon\Big) + \left|\mathbb{E}[e^{itY_{un}}K] - \mathbb{E}[e^{itM}K]\right|.
$$
Letting $n\to\infty$, we get
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left|\mathbb{E}[e^{itX_n}K] - \mathbb{E}[e^{itM}K]\right|\le \sup|K|\cdot  \Big(2\limsup_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\left(|X_n-Y_{un}|>\varepsilon\right) + \varepsilon\Big).
$$
The claim now follows by first letting $u\to\infty$ and then $\varepsilon\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I  responded to hint in the comment according to the uniform convergence problem. What term of uniform convergence you are looking for? If you may look at my response to the hint, we may expect uniform convergence in Probability

Comment: @ziT, I don't see your point. Right now my post above answers your question. If you want an answer to some other question (e.g. specifying what precisely $Y_{un}$ is), please give an exact formulation of what you want to be answered.

Comment: I'm sorry and you are right. I wasn't aware that there are more assumptions needed. But i dont have much reputation left to start a bounty again for a question. I updated the question. It wasn't my intention to displease you or anything else.

Comment: can you say s.th. about the estimation of the upper bound $\leq \sup|K|\cdot ( 2P(|X_n-Y_{un}|>\epsilon)+\epsilon)$? What inequality you use there?

Comment: Now it is all clear. Thanks